# Override blog category location

Tags: joomla-3.x, overrides, template-override, category-blog

I'm new to overrides and want to change the look of the category blog that I've assigned to my menu item type.

I can't find which override to create and which file to edit.

It's the blog layout that shows the content (not a list) of all articles under a specified category.

Seems like I'm missing a simple thing. Would appreciate if someone can point me to the correct override and file.

I am currently using the protostar template.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is just copying these files :

```
.../components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog_children.php
.../components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog_item.php
.../components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog_links.php
.../components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog.php
.../components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog.xml
```

to

```
.../templates/protostar/html/com_content/category/blog_children.php
.../templates/protostar/html/com_content/category/blog_item.php
.../templates/protostar/html/com_content/category/blog_links.php
.../templates/protostar/html/com_content/category/blog.php
.../templates/protostar/html/com_content/category/blog.xml
```